# ${{a+b\sqrt-7}\over{2}}$ as the root of a polynomial

Tags: complex-numbers, congruences

So, I need help in showing that for any integers $a$ and $b$, ${{a+b\sqrt-7}\over {2}}$ is the root of a quadratic polynomial with integer coefficients if and only if $a$ is congruent to $b (mod 2)$.

Really stuck on this one, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

In general, if $p + qi$ is a root of a polynomial with real coefficients, then so is $p - qi$. So in your case, the two roots are $(a \pm b\sqrt{-7})/2$. That means your equation must be a multiple of 
$$
\left(x - {{a+b\sqrt-7}\over {2}}\right)\left(x- {{a-b\sqrt-7}\over {2}}\right)
$$
which simplifies to 
$$
x^2 - ax + (a^2 + 7b^2)/4.
$$
Multiply through by 4 to get the quadratic
$$
4x^2 - 4ax + (a^2 + 7b^2) = 0.
$$

So those two are ALWAYS the roots of a quadratic with integer coefficients. If you add the restriction that the quadratic must be MONIC (i.e., coeff. of $x^2$ is $\pm 1$), then to make the first quadratic be an integer quadratic, you need that
$ a^2 + 7 b^2$ 
is divisible by $4$. It's easy to write $a = 2n+1$ and $b = 2k$ and see that the result is not divisible by 4, or $a = 2n$ and $b = 2k+1$. So for it to be divisible by 4, the two must have the same parity. And if they DO have the same parity, then $a^2 + 7b^2$ IS divisible by 4, so you're done.